# Query with offset returns overlapping data sets

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, offset, sql-limit

Initial attempts at getting a very simple pagination, using fetch n rows and then a subsequent call with offset, gives overlapping entries in Oracle.

I was expecting  the following to give me two unique sets of results.  1-100 and then 101-200 of the results that would have been returned if the first line had been set with a limit of 200.

```
select  * from "APPR" /*+ index(APPR APPR_IDX01) */ where  ("APPROVER" = 'A') or  ("APPROVER" > 'A') order by "APPROVER"  fetch first 100 rows only ;

select  * from "APPR" /*+ index(APPR APPR_IDX01) */ where  ("APPROVER" = 'A') or  ("APPROVER" > 'A') order by "APPROVER" offset 100 rows fetch next 100 rows only ;
```

So if there are 150 items for approver A the first results should be:

- A, item1
- ....
- A, item100

The subsequent call (offset by 100) giving

- A, item101
- ...
- A, item150
- B, item1
- B, item2
- ....
- B, item201

Unfortunately the second set contains some entries from the first batch of values. Probably a really silly error, but I can't find an explanation as to why this should happen.

---- Updated as a result of comments
The Primary key consists of Approver and several other fields which together form a composite and unique primary.

The code will be called through ODBC and will be used on Oracle and MySQL back-end.

Comment: What is the primary key of your table?

Comment: The primary key consists of the "approver" and a composite of several other columns identifying the item to be approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, if you make "order by" to a column containing same values (like you have - 'A', 'A', 'A' ...) the order of records inside 'A' values will be random.

Please try to change your queries to  ... `order by "APPROVER", rowid` ...

Comment: Random, oh, had assumed that there would be some 'natural' order that would persist between queries.The solution, being first developed in Oracle, is to be called through ODBC interface and will need to work on MySQL too.

Comment: Added a column with a unique auto incrementing number, so solution is universal on Oracle and MySQL along with comments from @GMB this provides the solution

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, `APPROVER` is not a unique column. Since there may be duplicates, the `order by` claus is not stable, and the offset clause might generate duplicates.

A simple solution is to add more columns to the `order by` to break the ties. Assuming that `(approver, item)` is a unique set of columns, that would be:

```
select  * 
from appr
where approver = 'A' or approver > 'A'
order by approver, item
fetch first 100 rows only
-- then: offset 100 rows fetch next 100 rows only
```

Notes:

- there is no need to surround all-caps identifiers (tables or column names) with double quotes: that's the default in Oracle already
- parentheses around the `or` conditions are superfluous in this simple case
- if `approver` is always one character long, then the `where` clause can be simplified as `where approver >= 'A'`
- use index hints only if you really know why you are doing it (I am not saying you don't, but I removed it, just in case); most of the time, the database knows better

Comment: Correct "APPROVER" is not unique. 
Initial tests had not shown duplicates, but when up-scaled they appeared. Noted about parentheses they are only included as code forms a set of queries following a similar pattern, some of which rely on brackets to enforce precedence. Approver is only a single character to simplify the question. Noted on index hints - they were added only after studying and timing Explain plans.